# How to set element value of dynamically created drop down?

Tags: javascript, html

I used arrays of strings to populate drop downs. How do I set the value of each drop down option to the same as the text content?

`el.value = opt;` doesn't appear to work.

```js
var validCoursesKeys = ['opt 1','opt 2','opt 3','opt 4']
var validKeys = document.getElementsByClassName("validKeys");

setFields("courses");

function setFields(browser) {
    //document.getElementById("result").value = browser;

    var menuCounter = 1;

    if (browser == "courses") {
        for (var i = 0; i < validCoursesKeys.length; i++) {
            var opt = validCoursesKeys[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");

            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;

            for (var j = 0; j < validKeys.length; j++) {
                var elementClone = el.cloneNode(true);
                elementClone.id = menuCounter;
                menuCounter++;
                validKeys[j].appendChild(elementClone);
            }
        }
    } else if (browser == "rooms") {
        var menuCounter = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < validRoomsKeys.length; i++) {
            var opt = validRoomsKeys[i];
            var el = document.createElement("option");

            el.textContent = opt;
            el.value = opt;


            for (var j = 0; j < validKeys.length; j++) {
                var elementClone = el.cloneNode(true);
                elementClone.id = menuCounter;
                menuCounter++;
                validKeys[j].appendChild(elementClone);

            }
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<select class="validKeys"></select>
<select class="validKeys"></select>
<select class="validKeys"></select>
```

Comment: What currently happens when you set the value like how you are?

Comment: You need to loop the `validKeys` and `appendChild(el)`. You are just creating elements

Comment: @baao sorry i accidentally only copied part of my code. can you look again? i edited the OP.

Comment: @tymeJV i can't seem to print any of the values in the drop down.

Comment: You code works fine @stumpylumpy

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki ok thanks, maybe we're just grabbing the values incorrectly...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using jquery. See below updated code using jquery

```
   var validKeys = document.getElementsByClassName("validKeys");
    function setFields(browser) {
   //document.getElementById("result").value = browser;

  var menuCounter = 1;

   if (browser == "courses") {
    $.each(validCoursesKeys , function(index, keys) {
        var content='<option value="' + keys + '">' + keys + '</option>';
        validKeys.append(content);
    });
   } else if (browser == "rooms") {
    var menuCounter = 1;
    $.each(validRoomsKeys , function(index, keys) {
        var content='<option value="' + keys + '">' + keys + '</option>';
        validKeys.append(content);
     });
  }
};
```

Comment: Be careful, there's no jQuery tag in the OP.

Comment: my suggestion was to use Jquery rather than implementing it in a very crud way. If you want to use jquery then please include jquery library in your code.